# How can I exchange data between nodejs and puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I made a nodejs application that starts from index.js.
Then, index.js launches puppeteer and injects bot.js on a headless-api page by addscripttag function.

I made index.js sets a cookie for conveying initial values before injecting javascript, but I need more common way to exchange data.

I thought two ways; the first is using cookie, and the second is networking via socket connection.

Is there other way for send and receive data between index.js(node) and puppeteer(headless chrome)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, puppeteer IS nodejs side application, so they have a single environment and you don't need to "send" anything. Just pass data around as you'd do in any other JS code. I assume you want to transfer data between page and nodejs then.

To pass data from nodejs to page use [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). You can call any code in page context, ranging from simply setting some variables to directly calling whatever functions with necessary arguments.

To initiate transfer from page side to nodejs, first register a nodejs-side callback function with [page.exposeFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) and then call it from page code and it will be executed in nodejs context. Just like in previous case, everything else depends on code of that function. It can be as simple as storing whatever argument you pass to it in some variable or directly perform with data pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: thanks :) I've read your advise, and now I can implement my ideas